# LocalBroadcastManager receiving all broadcasts with same action string on emulator(4.4.2) but not on phone(4.0.4)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Broadcast receiver:

```
public class OrderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
             if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
                //reference 1
                //do some work
                LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext);
                intent.setAction("com.gndp.message.RECEIVED");
                lbm.sendBroadcast(intent);
             }   
             else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
                //reference 2
                //do some work
                LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext);
                intent.setAction("com.gndp.message.RECEIVED");
                lbm.sendBroadcast(intent);
             }
        }
```

inside Activity:

```
onCreate(){
    BroadcastReceiver deviceRegisteredBroadcastReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //reference 3
                if(intent.getStringExtra("data1")==null){
                    //code 1
                }
                else{
                    //code 2
                }
            }
}
onResume(){
    LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext);
    lbm.registerReceiver(deviceRegisteredBroadcastReciever, new IntentFilter("com.gndp.message.RECEIVED"));
}
```

on emulator, code reaches:

> reference 1------> reference 3

and

> reference 2------>reference 3

but on device, code reaches:

> reference 1------>reference 3

and

> reference 2---X--->reference 3 (it reaches ref. 2 but broadcast is not recieved at ref. 3)

and there is no error in logcat. Here's my androidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.gndp.OrderReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.gndp" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Perhaps your process is being terminated before the `RECEIVE` GCM broadcast arrives, and so your activity is gone at that point.

Comment: @CommonsWare The device's screen is always on and activity is in foreground all this time. Is it still possible that process is being terminated?

Comment: No, that rules out that scenario.